# How can I debug an intermittent unhandled exception "Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, unhandled-exception

I'm getting an intermittent UnhandledException `Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual` but the stacktrace references only System.* and MS.* calls.  It looks like a `DatePicker` was left-mouse clicked, and was trying to toggle a pop-up (I'm guessing the calendar widget). There are lots of `DatePicker`s in this application. I don't know which one caused the exception.

How can I debug this?

```
UnhandledException: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.
    at System.Windows.Media.Visual.AddVisualChild(Visual child)
    at System.Windows.Documents.NonLogicalAdornerDecorator.set_Child(UIElement value)
    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean asyncCall)
    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker.OnIsDropDownOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
    at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
    at System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker.TogglePopUp()
    at System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker.DropDownButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
    at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
    at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
    at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
    at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
    at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
    at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
    at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
    at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
    at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
    at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
    at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
    at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
    at MyProject.src.App.Main()
```

Comment: Is it related to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622571/popup-visual-tree-can-not-be-generated-again-when-user-switch-the-theme) by any chance? My best suggestion for debugging would be to google the key words (something like *"wpf DatePicker.TogglePopUp exception disconnect"*) and see what you can find... if it's an exception with the MS control, someone else will probably have encountered it before. Other than that, check to see if something you are doing is out of ordinary, such as background threading.

Comment: The users have confirmed they are not switching themes.  This is only occurring on a single production machine (dozens of other installations are working fine).  The OS is Windows Server 2012 R2.  I cannot reproduce this on my dev machine.  I've googled around and the results I've found are also never able to repro the issue.

Comment: I've been having this exact same problem and have been unable to find an answer.  Were you able to figure this out?  In my case I just trapped the error in the App_DispatcherUnhandledException and absorbed it but users complain that it locks up the calendar and they have to manually enter the date.  I too don't know which datepicker control is throwing the error but I believe it's one of the ones in the ribbon menu.  Also the app is running in Windows Server 2012 R2 over RDP.  I'd also like to know why you got a down vote, this is a real problem and we're trying to seek a resolution!

Comment: I haven't solved it, no, but we're in the same boat re: Windows Server 2012 R2 and DispatcherUnhandledException.  Another thing we have in common is my users are also running over RDP.  That might have something to do with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug the visual tree if the following exception occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575775/how-to-debug-the-visual-tree-if-the-following-exception-occurs)

Comment: Thanks for the link @WaiHaLee. That answer just says the error has "many different causes" and lists a few, none of which apply to my situation.